# AutoSize for BarEditItem - DevExpress

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress-windows-ui

I have a toolbar of type Dev Express xtraBar. Its not a ribbon control.
It contains a type of BarEditItem.
I need the width of BarEditItem to be variable , how can this be done in code? I mean if its inside a docked container and I resize the docked container the edit item  should resize...

The BarEditItem contains a Combo box inside it...

Answer (score 0):

As long as your BarEditItem is not MultiLine and not in a ribbon, setting the AutoFillWidth should accomplish what you are looking for. See [DevExpress AutoFillWidth documentation](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraBarsBarEditItem_AutoFillWidthtopic).